# 13.10 install on HP mini 2133

Tags: installation, resolution, hp

I wanted to install 13.10 on my Hp mini 2133, but main problem is that screen resolution during installation is not optimal for Hp mini 2133, and therefore all dialogs are too big, so I cannot see buttons area: BACK, NEXT.. Even windows cannot be resized less.

Is there any possibility to change installation screen resolution, maybe some boot parameters ?

Note: I am installing it from USB disk, bootable made in YUMI.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is another minimal official ISO, which is not as well-known as the „normal“ one.
[You can download it right here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

The major difference between this ISO and the other is that this one offers a command line installation, which should  solve your problem. 
During the installation make sure that you install the Ubuntu Desktop.

I hope this helps.